# workweek calculation based on if criteria

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am having trouble creating a formula in sharepoint that will calculate a field [Due] in business days (Monday-Friday), based of multiple IF statements. I posted this on the stackoverflow site but think it belongs here.

`For Example, in a dropdown [Test] the user has 1,2,3 and in [Date]=7/21/2014, in [Time]=11:00AM.`

`Test 1 has +2 adding on to the Date Test 2 has +4 adding on to the Date Test 3 has +6 adding on to the Date`Test 1 has +2 adding on to the Date Test 2 has +4 adding on to the Date Test 3 has +6 adding on to the Date'

'The user selects Test 1 so the TAT is calculated to be 7/23/2014 but IF Test 2 is selected the TAT is calculated to be 7/24/2014 but IF Test 3 is selected then the Due is 7/28/2014 (excludes weekends). Thanks.'

'If [Time] was > 12:00PM then 1 additional day would be adding on to each (so +2 would be +3, +4 would be +5, and +6 would be +7.'

Comment: so how does your formular look so far?

Comment: 'code'=IF(([Test])="1",IF(WEEKDAY([Date])<3,[Date]+4,IF(WEEKDAY([Date])=7,[Date]+5,[Date]+6)),IF(WEEKDAY([Date])<5,[Date]+9,IF(WEEKDAY([Date])=7,[Date]+10,[Date]+11)))'code'.... I apologize if I did not do the code tags properly, I am new to sharepoint and the code doesn't seem to account for time at all, but I hope its a good start.  Thanks

Comment: have you tested your formula in excel?

Comment: Yes and it works, but it only accounts for one test and does not account for time at all.  Thanks.